# How do I add cluster markers to Gmaps4rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, coffeescript, gmaps4rails

I was able to add the marker cluster in this format inside of the index.html.erb file. When I decided to add infowindows that is when my map started to break.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google',
    {markers:
      {clusterer: {
        gridSize: 60,
        maxZoom: 20,
        styles: [ {
          textSize: 10,
          textColor: '#ff0000',
          url: 'assets/creative/m1.png',
          height: 60,
          width: 60 }
        , {
          textSize: 14, 
          textColor: '#ffff00',
          url:'assets/creative/m2.png',
          height: 60,
          width: 60 }
        , {
         textSize: 18, 
         textColor: '#0000ff',
         url: 'assets/creative/m3.png',
         width: 60,
         height: 60}
        ]}}}
    );
        handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
             markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
            handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
            handler.fitMapToBounds();

        });
```

When I add infowindows to my web app under my custom.js.coffee file as

```
class InfoBoxBuilder extends Gmaps.Google.Builders.Marker 

create_infowindow: ->
return null unless _.isString @args.infowindow

boxText = document.createElement("div")
boxText.setAttribute('class', 'panel panel-green') 
boxText.innerHTML = @args.infowindow
@infowindow = new InfoBox(@infobox(boxText))


infobox: (boxText)->
content: boxText
pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
boxStyle:
  width: "280px"

@buildMap = (markers)->
handler = Gmaps.build 'Google', { builders: { Marker: InfoBoxBuilder} 
} 
handler = Gmaps.build 'Google', { builders: { markers:
      {clusterer: {
        gridSize: 60,
        maxZoom: 20,
        styles: [ {
          textSize: 10,
          textColor: '#ff0000',
          url: 'assets/creative/m1.png',
          height: 60,
          width: 60 }
        , {
          textSize: 14, 
          textColor: '#ffff00',
          url:'assets/creative/m2.png',
          height: 60,
          width: 60 }
        , {
         textSize: 18, 
         textColor: '#0000ff',
         url: 'assets/creative/m3.png',
         width: 60,
         height: 60}
        ]}}} }  #dependency injection

  handler.buildMap { provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'} }, ->
  markers = handler.addMarkers(markers)
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers)
  handler.fitMapToBounds()
```

I get the marker cluster working but I lose the infowindow formatting. How do I inject the infowwindow and the marker cluster code into the custom.coffee.js file.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I first converted the infobox builder from coffeescript to plain old vanilla javascript and then after the first dependency injection I added the marker cluster dependency. I added the following code to the view.

```
    var InfoBoxBuilder, handler,
      extend = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; },
      hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty;

    InfoBoxBuilder = (function(superClass) {
      extend(InfoBoxBuilder, superClass);

      function InfoBoxBuilder() {
        return InfoBoxBuilder.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
      }

      InfoBoxBuilder.prototype.create_infowindow = function() {
        var boxText;
        if (!_.isString(this.args.infowindow)) {
          return null;
        }
        boxText = document.createElement("div");
        boxText.setAttribute('class', 'panel panel-green');
        boxText.innerHTML = this.args.infowindow;
        return this.infowindow = new InfoBox(this.infobox(boxText));
      };

      InfoBoxBuilder.prototype.infobox = function(boxText) {
        return {
          content: boxText,
          pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
          boxStyle: {
            width: "280px"
          }
        };
      };

      return InfoBoxBuilder;

    })(Gmaps.Google.Builders.Marker);

        handler = Gmaps.build('Google', {
          builders: {
            Marker: InfoBoxBuilder
          },
           markers:
                  {clusterer: {
                    gridSize: 60,
                    maxZoom: 20,
                    styles: [ {
                      textSize: 10,
                      textColor: '#ff0000',
                      url: 'assets/creative/m1.png',
                      height: 60,
                      width: 60 }
                    , {
                      textSize: 14, 
                      textColor: '#ffff00',
                      url:'assets/creative/m2.png',
                      height: 60,
                      width: 60 }
                    , {
                     textSize: 18, 
                     textColor: '#0000ff',
                     url: 'assets/creative/m3.png',
                     width: 60,
                     height: 60}
                    ]}}
        });
        handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
                         markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
                        handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
                        handler.fitMapToBounds();

                    });
```

Now I can have both marker clusters and a custom infowindow for each of my locations.